# Loop a variable inside an sql query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to work out the following,

I am querying a Salesforce db with PHP, an seems that they don't really allow relationship queries, which is my whole problem, so need to run 2 queries, a query first to populate a variable that is used into a second query right after.

That variable will hold a string with usernames, just plain text usernames, that I need to match with an Id that will match a OwnerId after,

something like this,

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT FirstName FROM User WHERE Id in (SELECT OwnerId from Case WHERE Region__c = 'WORLD' and CaseOwnerManager__c = 'some_guy' AND Status = 'Open')";

$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);

for ($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
        $record = $queryResult->current();
        $firstName = $record->fields->FirstName;

        echo $firstName."<br>\n";
    }

$query = "SELECT CaseNumber, Status FROM Case where Status = 'Open' and OwnerId in (SELECT Id FROM User where FirstName = '{$firstName}')";

$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);

for($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
        $record = $queryResult->current();

        $caseNumber = $record->fields->CaseNumber;
        $status     = $record->fields->Status;

        echo $caseNumber."<br>\n";
        echo $status."<br>\n";

    }?>
```

Of course, in the above, the second query, the one with the $firstName variable, it picks up the last value of the string and then the loop gives the CaseNumber and Status of that single user.

So what i need to do is get that second query in some sort of loop and while it is looping, get the $firstName variable to loop as well.

So at the end, $firstName should populate the th of a table and $caseNumber and $status its tds

Any ideas on how to do it, or if it even can be done?

Cheers.

Comment: HI! why u dont open 2 connection to the database and put the 2nd query inside the first loop, but using another connection?

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, if that should work maybe i didn't write it properly...i'll give another go...

Comment: Got it working. It's not pretty, but work, I guess that now I can break it down into functions. Cheers.

Comment: Wow nice! ;)
Take a look here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm